# Jelastic - "Container return error message: getopt: invalid option -- 'a'"

Tags: tomcat, jelastic

I'm trying to install a web application into a tomcat environment in Jelastic but it returns the following error:

```
{
  "result": 4099,
  "source": "JEL",
  "error": "Container return error message: getopt: invalid option -- 'a'"
}
```

My first guess it's a Jelastic issue because I tried to deploy the same application into a tomcat locally and it works fine. I hope you guys can help me out with this issue!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I recommend to contact your hosting provider with full details how to reproduce (e.g. which application you're trying to deploy from your deployment manager in the dashboard). They should be able to check it more deeply.

Comment: Also, did you get the same problem with another standard application? Maybe XWiki WAR file or something like that.

Comment: @Damien-Layershift I did,actually the same application yesterday was working fine and today I just made a few updates, nothing expressive, and once I faced the issue I got back to the previous working version and I got the same issue, so I don't know if this is an application problem. Perhaps contact the host provider is the best choice (or the only one) in thi case. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Felipe Belluco, it seems that this is a specific case which requires detailed analysis. Could you please provide me with the name of the environment and which hosting you are using?

Comment: @Aless apparently the problem is solved, I didn't do anything new and it came back to normality the day after. I don't what really happened, but it's working fine now! Thanks a lot!